# Java: Passing an array to println

Tags: java, arrays

The following is a contrived example I just made up to help me understand the inner workings of java.

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] a;
        a = new int[12];
        System.out.println(a);


    }
}
```

This prints out some garbage. Since a is passed by reference, I presume `println` gets the memory address of a, and threats it as a string. I'am right here? Can you elaborate what happens exactly? Thanks. (note: I am not interested in how to print an array. I know that.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

An array is treated as an object, so the default outcome of [`Object#toString()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#toString%28%29) will be used as string representation. See also this extract of the Javadoc (click the link):

> The toString method for class Object returns a string consisting of the name of the class of which the object is an instance, the at-sign character `@', and the unsigned hexadecimal representation of the hash code of the object. In other words, this method returns a string equal to the value of:
>
> ```
>     getClass().getName() + '@' + Integer.toHexString(hashCode())
> ```

To achieve what you want, rather use [`Arrays#toString()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#toString%28java.lang.Object%5B%5D%29).

```
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(a));
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is printing the memory address. See the Q&A section here: http://www.cs.princeton.edu/introcs/14array/ Use `Arrays.toString(a)` to convert the array `a` into a `String` which can be printed if you want to output the array's contents.

Comment: not memory address, but hash code (maybe an address, must not)...

Answer (score 0):

`println()` calls the `toString()` method of whatever you pass to it. In the case of an array, this results in some hashcode representing the array object.