# Why do I get garbage values when print arrays in Java?

Tags: java, arrays

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Simplest way to print an array in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/409784/simplest-way-to-print-an-array-in-java)

How do I even print arrays? I'm trying to experiment on some methods and all I keep on getting are garbage values. I tried to import the Arrays library - still didn't work.

```
    int []x = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
    int []y;
    y = x.clone();
    System.out.println(x);
    System.out.println(y);
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Simplest way to print an array in Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/409784/simplest-way-to-print-an-array-in-java), http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4297361, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8410294, ...

Answer (score 6):

Isn't garbage. Is the default implementation of `toString` for this class.

The easiest way to get the elements printed on a readable format is:

```
String printed = Arrays.toString(x);
```

Documentation for [Arrays.toString(int[])](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#toString%28int%5b%5d%29)

The same approach can be used to print out array of `primitives` and `Objects`.

Answer (score 5):

It is not a garbage value; it is the  `toString()` implementation of `int[]`,

If you want to print the contents of array

```
public void printArray(int[] arrray){
 for(int number: array){
   System.out.println(number);
 }
}
```

---

**See Also**

- [Why isn't there a java.lang.Array class? If a java array is an Object, shouldn't it extend Object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8546500/why-isnt-there-a-java-lang-array-class-if-a-java-array-is-an-object-shouldnt)

Comment: Yup - and see [Arrays.toString()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#toString%28int[]%29) and its like for potentially nicer ways to print them.