# java - using elements from returned array

Tags: java, arrays

`get1()` method returns an array. I do get the output but the value from `get1()` is `[D@addbf1`

My question is there any way to directly use the returned array to get the values in `inf1[0]` and `inf1[1]` and show it in the output statement?

I am aware of other ways of showing the output. But I want to know whether I can directly retrieve elements of the returned array.

```
class vehicle{
   double [] inf1 = new double[2];
   void set(double d, double s) {
     inf1[0]=d;
     inf1[1]=s;
   }
   double[] get1() {
     return inf1;
   }
}

public class calc2 {
   public static void main(String args[]) {
     vehicle ob = new vehicle();
     ob.set(56.24, 75);
     System.out.println("The time taken to cover "+ob.get1());
   }
}
```

Comment: Similar: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11399950/why-do-i-get-garbage-values-when-print-arrays-in-java/11399956#11399956

Comment: possible duplicate of [Simplest way to print an array in Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/409784/simplest-way-to-print-an-array-in-java)

Comment: @JigarJoshi Way to point to your answer instead of what that post duplicated :)

Comment: You get the output of [D@addbf1 because you're printing the reference. So its printing the reference of the array returned by the method instead of the elements like you expected.

Comment: @Jigar...your link did not answer my question. But I learnt something new. thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can reference the elements of the array via the `get1()` method:

`get1()[0]` will work.

Answer (score 6):

> My question is there any way to directly use the returned array to get the values in inf1[0] and inf1[1] and show it in the output statement?

Sure:

```
double[] result = obj.get1();
System.out.println("Result: " + result[0] + "," + result[1]);
```

Or:

```
System.out.println("Result: " + Arrays.toString(obj.get1());
```

The `[D@addbf1` is *just* the result of calling `toString()` on an array. If you want to get at the values within an array, you normally just access each element individually using an array index expression: `array[index]`

(It's not clear whether your question is really about *accessing* the array values, or converting an array into text for display purposes.)

Comment: my question was for accessing. Thanks and your suggestion also worked for me. I appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

try

```
System.out.println("The time taken to cover "+ob.get1()[0]);
```

`ob.get1()` will return your array so you can now use `[index]` on it.

Comment: @user547453 Glad I could help, but read also [answer that Jon Skeet gave](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11400660/1393766). It contains a loot of useful info.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a collection class like ArrayList.

Declare
`ArrayList<double> inf1 = new ArrayList<double>();`

In get1()

```
inf1.add(d);
inf1.add(s);
```

and in calc2,
`System.out.println("The time taken to cover "+ob.get1());`