# java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Empty key

Tags: java, exception, encryption, cryptography, illegalargumentexception

```
 public byte[] encryptWithAesKey(byte[] key, byte[] iv, byte[] data) {
      try {
             IvParameterSpec ivSpec = new IvParameterSpec(iv);
             Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CTR/NoPadding");
             SecretKeySpec aesKey = new SecretKeySpec(key, "AES");
             cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, aesKey, ivSpec);
             return cipher.doFinal(data);
          } catch (Exception e) {
             System.out.println("Error while encrypting: " + e.toString());
          }
     return null;
 }
```

at javax.crypto.spec.SecretKeySpec.(SecretKeySpec.java:96)

This is returning an exception but works well in android 28 lower.

StackTrace as follows:

```
System.out: encryptwithAES:[B@b8979fbIV:[B@78d7813data:[B@3841a50
System.err: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Empty key
System.err:    at javax.crypto.spec.SecretKeySpec.<init>(SecretKeySpec.java:96)
System.err:    at com..Security.SecurityController.encryptWithAesKey(SecurityController.java:93)
System.err:    at com..Controllers.Files.FileController.encryptAndSaveFile(FileController.java:75)
System.err:    at com..Controllers.Files.FileControllerRN.encryptAndSaveFileRN(FileControllerRN.java:68)
System.err:    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
System.err:    at com.facebook.react.bridge.JavaMethodWrapper.invoke(JavaMethodWrapper.java:372)
System.err:    at com.facebook.react.bridge.JavaModuleWrapper.invoke(JavaModuleWrapper.java:151)
System.err:    at com.facebook.react.bridge.queue.NativeRunnable.run(Native Method)
System.err:    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:883)
System.err:    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:100)
System.err:    at com.facebook.react.bridge.queue.MessageQueueThreadHandler.dispatchMessage(MessageQueueThreadHandler.java:27)
System.err:    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214)
System.err:    at com.facebook.react.bridge.queue.MessageQueueThreadImpl$4.run(MessageQueueThreadImpl.java:226)
System.err:    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:919)
```

Comment: Um, seems your key consists of zero bytes. Which part of that is not clear?

Comment: 1) Why have you set tag "nullpointerexception", but in the title you wrote IllegalArgumentException? Please show the whole stack trace.

Comment: @mentallurg added.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This (or similar) is the code that is throwing the exception:

```
public SecretKeySpec(byte[] key, String algorithm) {
    if (key == null || algorithm == null) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Missing argument");
    }
    if (key.length == 0) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Empty key");
    }
    this.key = key.clone();
    this.algorithm = algorithm;
}
```

Notice that the exception is thrown when the `key` array has zero length.  Indeed, this is the **only situation** where a `SecretKeySpec` constructor will throw this exception with this message<sup>1</sup>.  So there no room for *any* doubt that this is what your code is doing.

Solution: fix the code that is calling your `encryptWithAesKey` so that it doesn't pass in a zero length byte array.

---

<sup>1 - This applies to the Sun / Oracle / OpenJDK codebase.  The Android implementation of `SecretKeySpec` constructor that I found uses a different message for this: "key.length == 0".  It appears that in newer versions of Android they must have changed the behavior to be more Java(tm) compliant.  Or alternatively, somehow your Android platform is using an OpenJDK-based crypto implementation.</sup>

---

> byte[] key is [B@b8979fb, I checked it.

That doesn't prove that the byte array is not zero length.  Please read this: [Why do I get garbage values when print arrays in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11399950/why-do-i-get-garbage-values-when-print-arrays-in-java)

In short, the `[B@b8979fb`  tells you that it is a non-null byte array, but absolutely nothing about its length or content.

> This is returning an exception but works well in Android 28 lower.

In the Android case you must be supplying a non-empty byte array.  The Android version will also fail (same exception, different message) if you supply an empty byte array as the key.

Comment: Thank you, getting into it now! The length is absolutely zero.

Comment: The only thing I don't understand is why does it work for other versions of Android?